# How to select the list of games with players from both teams in 1 row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Each game has 4 players with 2 players being on 1 team.

Games

```
|  GameID  |    GameStartDate         |     LastChange        |

|   1      |    01-Dec-21 12:58:20 PM | 01-Dec-21 12:58:20 PM |

|   2      |    01-Dec-21 12:58:20 PM | 01-Dec-21 12:58:20 PM |
```

Players

```
| Id | firstname | lastname  | lastchange             | enabled  |   

| 1  | Testing   | User      | 01-Dec-21 12:58:20 PM  | True     |

| 2  | Staff     | Shanns    | 30-Nov-21 1:22:51 AM   | True     |

| 4  | New       | User      | 01-Dec-21 12:58:20 PM  | True     |

| 5  | Sec       | User      | 01-Dec-21 12:58:20 PM  | True     |
```

Teams

```
| TeamID | GameID | IsWinner |

| 1      | 1      | True     |

| 2      | 2      | False    |

| 3      | 1      | False    |

| 4      | 2      | True     |
```

PlayerTeams

```
| Id    |  PlayerID |TeamID | Price |  

|  2    |  1        |   1   |  0    | 

|  3    |  2        |   1   |  0    | 

|  4    |  4        |   2   |  50   | 

|  6    |  5        |   2   |  50   | 

|  7    |  4        |   3   |  50   | 

|  8    |  5        |   3   |  50   | 

|  9    |  2        |   4   |  0    | 

|  10   |  1        |   4   |  0    |
```

I am stumped on how to go about getting a list of all games with their players and teams in a row if possible. Any suggestions or do I need to change how my tables are setup?

Sql - Server Version 13.00.1601

Expected results Row:

```
| GameID |GameStartDate | LastChange | Player1Team1Id |Player1Team1firstname | Player2Team1lastname |Player2Team1Id | Player2Team1firstname| Player2Team1lastname  | Player1Team2Id | Player1Team2firstname| Player2Team2lastname | Player2Team2Id |P layer2Team2firstname | Player2Team2lastname  | Sum(Price) as PriceTotal |
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: To avoid us guessing, please add your expected results.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I updated the question with the version of Sql Server and the expected results. Thank you.

Comment: @Stu I updated the question with the version of Sql Server and the expected results. Thank you.

Comment: How do you want to determine which is team 1? Lowest id, winner, lowest price, etc? Same question for how to determine which is player 1?  *(The reason you're struggling is that SQL is deliberately not good at this structure. It's **designed** to have each player on a different row, not a different column; a normalised format. Then your reporting layer lays it out as necessary.)*

Answer (score 0):

Try the below SQL:

```
select * from playerteams join players on playerteams.playerid = players.id
join teams on playerteams.teamid = teams.teamid
join games on teams.gameid = games.gameid
```

Comment: That gets each player on a different row. The OP specifically asked for them to be on the same row.